# Stuck in running mode while sorting

Tags: vba, excel, runtime, runtime-error

I am trying to sort the data on `sheet 2` to `sheet 9` by text in the string sby.

I think logic is simple from the code below.

But the code below gave

> runtime-error 1004; Select Method of Range Class Failed for the line   `wk.Rows(j).EntireRow.Select`

Update 1:

> I don't get the error now but it's stuck in [running] mode for a long time I had to break the code execution. I am trying to implement the I/O logic below. I think my code should work but it's either taking very long or stuck in an infinite loop. Can you help

Input:

```
col B
Commercial
Tech
Operation
Commercial
Commercial
.
.
.
.
```

Output:

```
col B
Commercial
Commercial
Commercial
Tech
Operation
.
.
.
```

Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub SortByCommercial()
Dim wk As Worksheet
Dim sby, FinalRow, i, j, p
Dim WsCount As Integer
WsCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

sby = "Commercial"

For i = 2 To WsCount

Set wk = Sheets(i)
FinalRow = wk.Range("A900000").End(xlUp).Row
p = FinalRow + 1

    For j = 2 To FinalRow
        If Trim(wk.Range("B" & j).Text) <> sby Then

            wk.Rows(j).EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Cut

            wk.Range("A" & p).Select
            wk.Paste

            Rows(j).EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

            Range("A1").Select

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
            j = j - 1
        Else: End If
    Next j

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Option explicit requires all variables to be dimensioned.  sby and a few other variables are not dimensioned.

Comment: @Jason_Walker No I don't think that's the problem

Comment: After
    Set wk = Sheets(i)
Type
    sheets(i).activate

Comment: @Jason_Walker Thanks I don't get the error now but it's stuck in `[running]`  mode for a long time I had to break the code execution. I am trying to implement the logic mentioned in the question. I think my code should work but it's not working. Can you help ?

Comment: Are you wanting column B sorted alphbetically or "Commercial" first and everything else after regardless of order?

Comment: @Jason_Walker Actually I don't want to sort just the col but entire row. Sort depends on text in string `sby` and not alphabetically

Comment: @Jason_Walker okay I think I got it where it's stuck obviously the last row wont be `=' Commercial and it will always move it on the next row and delete that row this will go on forever

Comment: If you're ever adding or deleting rows then reverse the order of the loop. Instead of `For j = 2 To FinalRow` use `For j = FinalRow To 2 Step -1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub SortByCommercial()
Dim wk As Worksheet
Dim sby, FinalRow, i, j, p
Dim WsCount As Integer
WsCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim lngRowTemp as Long
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

sby = "Commercial"

For i = 2 To WsCount

    Set wk = Sheets(i)
    Sheets(i).Activate        

    For j = 2 To FinalRow
        FinalRow = wk.Range("A900000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        lngRowTemp = FinalRow -1

        If Trim(wk.Range("B" & j).Text) <> sby Then
            wk.Rows(j).EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Cut
            wk.Range("A" & FinalRow).Select
            wk.Paste
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next j

    for j = lngRowTemp to 2 step -1
        if cells("B" & j).value = "" then
            cells("B" & j).EntireRow.Delete
        end if
    next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Thanks please change the delete blank rows code part with  `Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete` otherwise everything was good except that.